# Excel-Grouping like numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that contains a column for debits and a column for credits.  By inserting a column and using formula `=IF(B1="",C1,B1)` and then sorting by that new column I was able to get the like debits and credits stacked one on top of the other.

My task now is to move all the lines that have like debits and credits to the top (or a separate sheet) and all the lines that do not have like debits and credits to the bottom (or a separate sheet).  In other words I would like to get lines `1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11` separated from lines `3`, `6`, and `8`.

Example:

[image: mixture of like and non-like numbers]

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to use a new column E and write:

`=IF(COUNTIF($D$1:$D$6198,D1)>1,1,"")`

No need to Format as Table just as it is and drag it down
D1:D6198 is the new column with your formula `=IF(B1="",C1,B1)` already done by you

You will have 1 if you have the same number more than once (5777047-->1...)
If just once empty ""
You can sort the result according to column E

**Update for removing the formula in D**

`=IF(OR(COUNTIF($C$1:$C$6198,B1)>0,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6198,C1)>0),1,"")`

Write this formula in D1 and drag it down
do not format as Table no need
You will have 1 If the same number is in Debit and credit and "" empty if only in one column
And now sort by column D
(You can copy paste special value in another sheet the corresponding rows)

Comment: So, I'm going to add formulas to columns E AND D?

Comment: no you already wrote your own in D, just in E the If formula

Comment: Do I need the formula in column D?

Comment: Did you remove it I can arrange the formula if you remove it

Comment: Formula updated

Answer (score 0):

Format your data as a table.  In Column E, find matches for ColC with ColB.  For example, in E1, this formula:

`=match(C1, B$1:B$11,0)`

...would find whether there is a match for the value in c1 *anywhere* in B1:B11.

You want to save rows for which either C is present in ColB or B is present in ColC:

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,B$2:B$12,0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,C$2:C$12,0))),1,0))`

Fill down.

Now the rows that are duplicated will have a 1 in Column E, others will have a 0.

Sort by Column E.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I entered your formula but am getting an error message.  After I say OK it highlights the second quotation mark.  If I remove it, it still gives me an error.

Comment: It auto-corrected the last comma to an asterisk but now am getting #VALUE!

Comment: Click on the cell to edit the formula.  Now click on the word match, so your cursor is in the middle of it.  Now flick on the italic "fx" to the left of the equation editing bar at the top of the screen.  You should get a popup showing lookup value, lookup array and match type.  Report those to me here

Comment: Maybe column B is more or less than B1:B11 change it to correspond your Data in column B

Comment: Lookup_value   C2
Lookup_array $B$1:B$6198   = {Column 2";5777047;0;0;2187969;0;...

Comment: Why 2" " is giving the error

Comment: what do you have in B1?

Comment: Is the header of column B is in B1 and it is Column 2?

Comment: When I formatted as a table it added headers.  B1 is now "Column2"

Comment: And your data shifted down a row?  Then adjust your formulas to reflect that (`B$2:B$12, or whatever)

Comment: Is the formula to be =iferror(match(C2, B$2:B$6198,0), "-") 
If so, it doesn't like the last quotation mark.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why you are having trouble with that formula.  When I copy-paste from your comment, it works fine.  That said, I edited my answer to provide a new formula what should give even better function for you.

Comment: Good Morning,
Using =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,B$2:B$12,0)), ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,C$2:C$12,0))),1,0)), I got it to work.  But it's listing all the debits that are ones, and then all the credits that are ones.  I need each matching debit and credit to line up one below the other.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my original post; I need the debits and the credits to align together, such as lines 1 and 2 above.

So, I want to isolate the like debits and credits from debits or credits that don't have a corresponding amount, AND I need to group each matching DR/CR together.

Comment: BTW, in my original post, the way I got the numbers in column D was to use formula =IF(B1="",C1,B1), then sort by column D.

What I need now is to not have lines such as 3 and 6 in between the lines that have corresponding matching DR/CRs.

Is this possible?

Comment: The nice thing about using a table is that it is very easy to sort away the non matching lines and delete them. Then, as you suggest, you can resort by your original column D, which would put the similar together.  Alternately, instead of deleting the non-matches, you could right click on the table header triangle and filter them out - the data isn't destroyed, it is just hidden.

Comment: I don't want to delete the non-matching lines and I cannot filter.  I need to actually separate the matching from the non-matching.

If I use both formulas I can sort and get what I need.  I just wonder if there is an easier way.